# How can I split tag number of rfid as integer?

Tags: c#, arduino, rfid

I'm getting the information by reading the card, but how can I just get the tag number as int?

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
                serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            textRFID.Text += indata;
        }
```

[image: rfid-ss]

This is the string I need to parse:

```
"RFID tag detected Tag Type:\tMifare One (S50) The tag's number is:\t235717311 Read Checksum:\t238 Calculated Checksum:\t238"
```

Thanks to @haldo I can receive my tag number but it gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error and I put try catch, when I press ok to error, it goes and output is as I wanted. How can we remove this error?

Here is my editing code :

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            string contains = "The tag's number is:";
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            int tagNumber = 0;
            try
            {
                indata.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())      // split on newline chars
                      .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(contains)) // get first string matching pattern above 
                      .Split(':')                                    // split on ':'
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => int.TryParse(x, out tagNumber));  // return first successful try parse
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            textRFID.Text = tagNumber.ToString();            
        }
```

Comment: You could use regex to look for the pattern and capture the group of digits after "The tag's number is:", then parse that captured string as an int.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use String manipulators like `Substring` or `String.split('')`. you would get the `Tag number` and then use `Convert.ToInt(your tag number here)` to convert into `INT`. By default it is `string`. you need to convert it to `Integer`

Comment: thanks for advice. I edited my code but now it gives  "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. You've an idea?

Comment: A proper debugging would help. It means that somewhere an object has not been referenced to

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to look for the pattern and capture the group of digits after "The tag's number is:", then parse that captured string as an int.  Something like this:

```
string pattern = "The tag's number is:(\\d+)";
string indata = "blah blah \nasdfasdfasdf\nThe tag's number is:123389882\nasdfsadf\nfgjdjgjgd";
var matches = Regex.Match(indata, pattern);
int? tagNumber = null;

if (matches.Success)
{
    var grp = matches.Groups[1];
    string num = grp.Value;
    tagNumber = int.Parse(num);
}

// tagNumber is 123389882
```